# How to make good grouping of elements?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I want to make htmlpage like this . 
[image: Wonder table]

But i dont want to make 4 table for this 1 page.
What will be best way to make this (i will add some elements in cells after ) - Panel , Div , or something else ? Wait for good advice .
P.S. i write in Asp.Net / CSS  .

Comment: Did you at least tried to do something? Dont ask for someone else to code it for you. Try to do it yourself and then ask for help.

Comment: @PLAudet , i tried to make it through Table , Panel and Div . And these variants are bad for me.

Comment: Div is always a good choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't state what contents should come on the page and how should they be placed. I'm just guessing what your page might look like and would suggest you to use the appropriate elements provided in HTML5. For the top area you could use:

```
<header role="banner><!-- your contents --></header>
```

assuming it contains title, logo or similar.

The central part could be wrapped by the element `main`:

```
<main role="main">
    <section>Section1</section>
    <section>Section2</section>
    <section>Section1</section>
</main>
```

The part taking the menu i.e. navigation should be marked up with:

```
<nav role="navigation">
<!-- menu entries -->
</nav>
```

The bottom part could be marked up as:

```
<footer role="footer">
    <!-- if you need two different containers inside -->
    <div id="footer-left"></div>
    <div id="footer-right"></div>
</footer>
```

This is just a rough example that should give you an idea how to proceed further.

Don't use tables for layouting the page as it is frowned upon. Position the elements using CSS3.

Good luck!

Comment: Great ! It'is that i need. But 1 question - why using of tables use tables for layouting is bad? Because they have uncomfortable to work , or its another reasons?

Comment: Tables should be used for tabular data, not for layouting. It breaks with the semantic of the page. You'll have a problem to create a responsive page if your complete content is in a table. There is an old discussion at StackOverflow about using tables for layout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html